# How to invoke Javascript or Ajax function from laravel backend(Controller or model)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel as my backend and blade templating engine for front end. After I submit a form I collect user's data like email, phone number etc. After submitting and successfully validating, I want to invoke a javascript/ajax function which should send a request to payment gateway.

Is there any way in which I can achieve this? Or any other solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Javascript's Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

You could try something like this (assuming you return a `success` value from the backend)

```
fetch('/your/backend/endpoint')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      response.json().then(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // redirect to payment portal
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

Of course you need to customise your Fetch call to include the post data, you can find some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) here.